# swiftui - how to reference the parent view from within a popup modal view? (code attached)

Tags: swiftui

With SwiftUI is there an easier way then the below to reference functions/logic in the parent view from within the model view?

In the below I had to create a reference function variable in the modal view, then manually pass this across.  Wondering if there is another way with less lines of code?  Able to just reference the calling view from the model view?

Background - Looking at scenarios where some logic might be stored in parent, or centralised into another file.  Perhaps logic associated with create/update/delete operations on a Core Data database, and then when in the modal view to say add another item one wants to call back to the centralised "create item" code.

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct GCParentView: View {
    @State private var showModal : Bool = false

    func addItemLogic() {
        print("addItemLogic")   // ** CONSOLIDATED LOGIC
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("parent")
            Button(action: {
                self.showModal=true
            }) {
                Text("Show Modal")
            }.sheet(isPresented: self.$showModal) {
                GCModalView(
                    addItemFunction: self.addItemLogic  // ** HAVE TO MANUALLY PASS REF?
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

struct GCModalView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var addItemFunction : () -> ()  // ** NEED TO HAVE VARIABLE TO ASSIGN TO?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("modal")
            Button(action: {
                self.addItemFunction()
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
                Text("Add Item & Exit")
            }
        }
    }
}

let gcParentView = GCParentView()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: gcParentView)
```

Comment: This *logic* does not relate to *view* (and cannot due to nature of SwiftUI view), so view, even parent one, is not a place for such logic. Move this logic into view model and transfer this view model into child view either directly, via constructor arguments, or injecting via environment object (depending on goals).

Comment: any particular good example code you've seen that does this with SwiftUI and using Core Data?   (some of the examples I have they put the core data code into each view using @FetchRequest)

Comment: `@FetchRequest` plays exactly view model role in such cases. It is absolutely the similar as if you'd do this manually, like `@ObservedObject var vm = SomeCustomFetcher()`, which would fetch records from codedata base and store in some published array.

Comment: ok - so I guess I have been pondering whether the various usages of core data read/updates via @FetchRequest across different swiftui views should be pulled together into one file....but perhaps you're saying ok from best practice not to bother doing this and just use FetchRequest in each of the different views as is?